# Unable to create database diagrams in SS 2000 using SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm unable to create database diagrams in a SS 2000 database using SSMS 2008. I am a domain admin of a different domain than where my databases reside (the domain trust relationships are such that I have the same privileges in both domains). When I goto my 2000 database in SSMS and right click the database diagrams I see only "Working with SQL Server 2000 diagrams", "Reports", and "Refresh". My SQLServer instance is set to a compatibility of 80 (SQLServer 2000). Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions of SQL Server later than 2000 cannot work with SQL Server 2000 diagrams.

Here is some [MSDN info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186552.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: I'm not working with existing SS 2000 diagrams as none were created.  I'm trying to create new ones.  The article you referenced seems to refer to existing 2000 diagrams.

Comment: It actually means that you can't work with SS 2000 diagrams full stop, either creating or editing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are using SSMS version 18.0 ?

Relationship diagrams feature is missing from that version.

Install 17.9 or 18.1 to get the diagrams to work.
Note that you must uninstall a previous version of SSMS to install a new one.

Comment: sorry, missed the date, probably not the right answer.